# update session array value in laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

i created a cart page in laravel and now i want to add discount code section in laravel so that with every discount code minus a price with every product in cart page.

my cart session for any product save in session like this:

```php
// product with id 1
  "cart_1" => [
    "id" => "1"
    "product" => "accounting"
    "quantity" => 5
    "price" => 50000
    "attr" => [
    // product options that some user choose this
      "torfehnegar_evidence" => "true"
    ]
  ]

// product with id 3
  "cart_3" => [
    "id" => "3"
    "product" => "programming"
    "quantity" => 2
    "price" => 600
    "attr" =>  [
      // product options that some user choose this
        ]
  ]
```

now when a user insert a discount code with price like `500` ,i want to this arrays change like this

```php
// product with id 1
  "cart_1" => [
    "id" => "1"
    "product" => "accounting"
    "quantity" => 5
    "price" => 49500 // the main price minus from discount price
    "attr" => [
    // product options
      "torfehnegar_evidence" => "true"
    ]
  ]

// product with id 3
  "cart_3" => [
    "id" => "3"
    "product" => "programming"
    "quantity" => 2
    "price" => 100 // the main price minus from discount price
    "attr" =>  [
      // product options
        ]
  ]
```

this changes must replace same session in laravel

Comment: and what have you tried so far to achieve your goal?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to implement a Service Container for that. This video shows you how to [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_z9nzEUgro4&list=PLpzy7FIRqpGD5pN3-Y66YDtxJCYuGumFO)